# Tailwind typography not working with multi-column React application shell

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I'm creating a React app using typescript and attempting to use one of Tailwind's multi-column application shells ([this one](https://tailwindui.com/components/application-ui/application-shells/multi-column#component-b639fa188098a2dbfd9f419c6ef9c6f3)), and then render some HTML using [Tailwind Typography](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/typography-plugin) via its `prose` class.

(I've yet to get Tailwind Typography to work as expected within an existing project. So, I started from scratch to try and isolate the issue with a very basic app.)

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "basic-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.4.2",
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.19",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.38",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.13"
  }
}
```

My tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
    require('@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio'),
  ],
}
```

src/index.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
    'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, 'Courier New',
    monospace;
}
```

My app.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import Example from "./routes/AppShell"

export default function App() {
  return <Example />;
}
```

My ./routes/AppShell.tsx is copy pasted from [this multi-column layout application shell](https://tailwindui.com/components/application-ui/application-shells/multi-column#component-b639fa188098a2dbfd9f419c6ef9c6f3).

Except I added this HTML contained by a `prose` class element:

```
{/* Primary column */}
<section aria-labelledby="primary-heading" className="min-w-0 flex-1 h-full flex flex-col lg:order-last">
  <h1 id="primary-heading" className="sr-only">
    Photos
  </h1>
  <article className="prose prose-lg">
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    <h2>Heading 2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    <h3>Heading 3</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    <h4>Heading 4</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>  
  </article>
</section>
```

**Yet, the typography plugin does not seem to kick in?!**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Silly mistake: for w/e reason my `tailwind.config.js` was not being used. Tailwind typography works now that those changes kicked in.

[image]